# Slow CPU + Windows Explorer + Everything when programming in C++ with OpenCV libraries no matter what IDE and Compiler used

Tags: performance, visual-c++, opencv, cpu, mingw32

When I was working with OpenCV, I added the build/install folder (i.e. where I had my mingw32-make and mingw32-install files created) to PATH variable. However, this made my PC quite slow after I did a few builds on my CodeBlocks IDE. I didn't forget to deallocate memory or anything like that which might cause trouble. Even a simple hello world program takes ages to run after a few builds. I am using i7 with 8GB of RAM and L3 cache which, I believe, is good enough for any development. After I removed the OpenCV directory from my PATH, it was okay, but not permanently. What could the problem be?

I also checked my environment variables and there is no garbage variable in there! I only have MinGW32 compiler i.e. the bin folder in PATH. But it is necessary (I think!).

Surprisingly, I have tried the same with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and when I try to build the openCV libraries, it really slows the PC down. For example, if I am trying to open the File explorer on Windows, it takes like 15 seconds for a window to pop up. If I try to open a web browser window, it takes about same time. And I have been monitoring my task manager for weird activities, but nothing! I don't know if it has something to do with Windows 7 64-bit OS.

I am not sure if it has something to do with CodeBlocks itself! I have another PC where I use Visual Studio 2010 Professional and it doesn't have the same problem.

I have manage to isolate the problem around the usage of MinGW compiler. The reason is that the problem occurs only when I am using it with an IDE (tried with Eclipse CDT, Dev CPP, and CodeBlocks). I got a stable release of MinGW downloaded from sourceforge.net which shouldn't have any major memory management issue with Windows Platform. Actually, the problem arises if I use it at all (doesn't start immediately, but after I have run my simply program a few times!).

My MinGW compiler is from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/

I couldn't find a very straightforward answer to this, so I am assuming that this is an unusual problem? If it is a repeated question by any chance which I have missed, please post a link to the comment and I will accept the answer. Ta

Comment: Hi, did you try to disable indexing? I don't know how Codeblock manage it, but I stoped to use Eclipse as a C++ ide because, indexer take a lot of CPU. Most of the time OpenCV is an easy to index library. So maybe the problem is not here.

Comment: @abarral       Fully agreed! Although I didn't allow any indexing if my memory serves me right! I will recheck codeblocks and see what on earth has gone wrong. Thanks for pointing that out! I gave you a +1 :)

Comment: @abarral        HIya! I forgot to mention something relevant to my question. Did you have this kind of problem when doing `mingw32-make` and `mingw32-make install`? I also found this to be making my CPU really slow. I don't know if they are having this indexing somewhere built-in!

Comment: It's normal that mingw32-make consume some CPU. Do you know if you use mingw32-make with an option like "-j" ? This option allow to compile file in parallel  using as much processor as possible. If you want to fastup your compilation, but keeping some CPU for you, you can add a number after "-j". This number will be the number of job run by make to compile. If you type "mingw32-make.exe -j4" 4 process of GCC will be launched, and with you i7 all must be good.

Comment: @abarral    Didn't work!!!! and I tried by unchecking a lot of plugins from CodeBlocks too. Nothing worked :(. I had some `delete` statements at the end of my code which I thought was unnecessary and removed them as well. But still nothing works! After I start code blocks and build my code for about 10 times, it is slower then a snail :(

Comment: @abarral        What I really don't understand is that how Micrsoft Visual Studio is immune from this??? And there is no indexing option (not that I managed to find) in Code Blocks. Jeez it is really hideous!!! And do I need to do a mingw32-get install g++ from command line after I add the MinGW\bin folder to PATH? It was suggested here cplusplus.com/forum/windows/28078

Comment: @abarral       NEW ISSUE!! I installed Visual C++ 2010 Express and tried to build openCV libraries using it. However, when I am building it, the explorer becomes really slow and even after the successful build, it doesn't recover from it. What is this now?

Comment: Really I don't know... Did you try to look in your task manager which process consume CPU ?

Comment: @abarral        I always keep my task manager open before I start it and there is nothing going on that I can see taking a lot of physical memory or CPU time. I really don't know what the problem is. By the way, I am using Windows 7 64 bit. I know most of the applications, even though they claim that they work, they don't actually stay quite stable when run on 64-bit OS. Do you think this might be the problem?

Comment: @abarral        Bad news now is that EVEN WINDOWS UPDATE is causing the same problem :(. I think that makes it OT for stackoverflow and probably an ideal topic for superuser.com.....thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that even my Windows Update search/install is causing the same problem....and also the problem desciption was raised in OpenCV http://answers.opencv.org/question/3996/cannot-do-anything-with-opencv-anymore-on-windows/

I am satisfied with the fact that my windows 7 is damaged somehow during SP1 installation and needs restoring/some other job. I have moved this to superuser.com as it may be OT for here.

**UPDATE**
I have now managed to fix it (apparently) by restoring the original image build of my laptop. I wish I didn't have to do that though! Microsoft's mess made me go through all these trouble!